# Show that the following set is a left ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals

> We have $R$ a commutative Ring with neutral Element. $M\subset R^n$ a $R$-submodule. Let $I_m$ be the set of matrices in $M_n(R)$(n matrices with elements in R) whose rows are elements of the submodule $M$. Show that $I_m$ is a left ideal of $M_n(R)$.

I tried taking the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and a lattice in $\mathbb{Z^2}$, composed from 2 random vectors. Then taking  $2\times2$ matrices. $I_m$ would be the set of matrices, whose row are integer combinations of these two vectors and since for the ideal i need for it to be closed under addition and left multiplication with elements of $M_n(R)$, i tried some examples and it worked.

But this is just an example and by no means a proof so I would really need some help.

Thanks in advance

Annalisa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this Ideal is a subgroup of $M_n(R)$ as addition of matrices breaks down to addition of vectors $m,n\in M$. As $M$ is an $R$-module, the addition $m+n\in M$.

Now take a matrix $A = \left(\begin{array} & a_1 & a_2 & ... & a_n\end{array}\right)^T\in I_M$ with rows $a_i\in M$.

Now let's take a look at the left-multiplication with another matrix $B \in M_n(R)$ with its rows $b_1,...,b_n\in R^n$. We now want to show that the rows of $B\cdot A$ are elements of $M$:

Let $c_i:=(BA)_i$ be the $i$-th row of the matrix product:

$$
c_i = b_i \cdot A = \sum_{j=0}^n b_{ij} \cdot a_{j}
$$

However, we have $b_{ij}\in R$ and as $M$ is an $R$-module we get $b_{ij}\cdot a_j \in M$. As $M$ is closed under addition we finally have $c_i \in M$ for all rows which shows that $B\cdot A \in I_M$ and $I_M$ is indeed a left ideal.

Comment: Very helpful. May i ask, is there any specific reason why we took the transpose?

Comment: Would all other left ideals be isomorphic to our $I_m$

Comment: Because the $a_i$ are representing the rows of $A$, but without the transpose, they would show the columns. Additionally i was too lazy to write the matrix with the rows directly

Comment: No, $\{0\}$ is a left-ideal as well and it's (in general) not isomorphic to $I_M$

Comment: is then any other relationship between the left ideals and $I_m$?

Comment: I have not that deep knowledge of abstract algebra. However, I don't think you can get a relevant relationship between other left ideals and $I_M$. $I_M$ is the canonical left ideal lifting the $R$-module $M$ to the set of matrices. That's the main thing to know about $I_M$ (at least what I can come up with)